# sql int to decimal with no storage

Tags: sql

I am currently writing in MS-SQL to convert old data to a new table and one of the variable in the old table is a int.  In the new table it has to be a decimal(10,3) because of the data now being entered.  The old data also has some nulls also.  When I convert the data using round to generate the new decimal I get a error:

> Msg 8115, Level 16, State 8, Line 1
>   Arithmetic overflow error converting int to data type numeric.

using the following code:

```
insert into Data_Exchange_Claims_History (Qty_Dispense)
select convert(decimal(10,3),round(ISNULL(Qty_Dispense, 0), 3))
from dbo.Data_Exchange_Claims_History_old c
```

Comment: The largest number in the column is 540000000 which need to be converted to 540000.000.  When I just do convert(decimal(13,3),Qty_Dispense) I get the decimal as 540000000.000  I am thinking that is why the error is being thrown because it see the new number as a 13 character number.  What I can not figure out is how to convert the number correctly to what I need.

Answer (score 4):

I assume the question is how it can fail;

An `INT` won't always fit into a `DECIMAL(10,3)`.

`DECIMAL(10,3)` means a total of 10 digits, of which 3 are to the right of the decimal point.

In other words, it can only represent integers up to `9999999`.

Answer (score 1):

An INT can fit into DECIMAL 10,3 only if it is <= 9,999,999
9,999,999 will turn into 9,999,999.000 (10 total digits, 3 decimals).

Answer (score 0):

After playing with the problem for a while it dawned on me that I just needed to move the decimal over three places so I divided the numbers by 1000 and it worked.  The new query looks like:

```
insert into Data_Exchange_Claims_History (Qty_Dispense)
select convert(decimal(10,3),(Qty_Dispense/1000))
from dbo.Data_Exchange_Claims_History_old c
```

Thanks to everyone who contributed to this as it helped me look at the problem in a new light.